# I am confused between current and current.next in linked list in python. When should we use them?

Tags: python, linked-list

In a linked list I used these two classes for Node and LinkedList. Now when adding different methods in linked list for different operations , we need to use while loop. we generally use (here we assign *current to head*  **current = self.head**)
`while current:` or `while current.next:` to iterate over the statements. I am confused how these two conditions are different and how it affects the loop. ***Is there any difference between these two conditions?***

```
    class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head = None):
        self.head = head


    #append function
    def append(self, data):
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:
                current= current.next
            current.next= data
        else:
            self.head = data


        #display function
    def show(self):
        current = self.head
        while current.next:
            print(current.value)
            current = current.next
            if not current.next:
                print(current.value)

         
             #insert
    def insert(self, new_element, position):
        counter = 1
        current = self.head
        if position > 1:
            while current and counter < position:
                if counter == position - 1:
                    new_element.next = current.next
                    current.next = new_element
                current = current.next
                counter += 1
        elif position == 1:
            new_element.next = self.head
            self.head = new_element
```

codes for two methods are attached . one uses `while current:` and the other uses `while current.next:`

Comment: One means "while there is an element at the current position" the other means "while there is an element at the following position" (which implies one at the current position as well).

Answer (score 0):

They mean something different. This code is using 'truthiness', the fact that every value in Python can evaluate to `True` or `False`. For an integer, `0` is `False`, anything else is `True`. For a string, `''` is `False`, anything else is `True`. Similarly, for an object reference (like `current` or `current.next`), `None` is `False`, anything else is `True`.

So, if the loop condition is `while current:`, that just means "keep doing this while `current` is not `None`", i.e. as long as `current` points to an item in the linked list. If the loop condition is `while current.next:`, that means "keep doing this while `current.next` is not `None`", i.e. as long as there's a `next` item in the linked list, after `current`.

Note that the `while` loop doesn't care about the type of the condition, it just evaluates its truthiness, and it only does so at the start of every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

There is an important difference

1. `while current:`

   This is what you use when you want to potentially process *all* nodes in the loop, and have no need to still have access to the last node once the loop finishes. After the loop finishes, `current` will be `None`.
2. `while current.next:`

   This is what you use when you want to *find* the last node in the list. After the loop finishes, `current` will be that final node. So this loop **stops one step earlier** than the other one. But there is a precaution to take: if `current` is `None` at the start of the loop, there will be an exception. So only use this when you are already sure that `current` is not `None`.

Now to the actual code where you use these loops:

### Case 1

```
current = self.head
if self.head:
    while current.next:
        current= current.next
    current.next= data
```

This is the second type. The purpose of the loop is to find the last node in the list. To avoid the potential exception, the loop is protected by `if self.head:`. At that moment `self.head` is referencing the same node as `current`, so it could also have been `if current.next:`. The statement *after* the loop, effectively uses the last node in the list in order to link a new node after it. If you would have done this with the first type of loop, you would already have lost the reference to the last node, and `current` would be `None`, making it impossible to still do `current.next = data`.

### Case 2

In the `show` function we also see the second type of loop:

```
current = self.head
while current.next:
    print(current.value)
    current = current.next
    if not current.next:
        print(current.value)
```

However, here it is not correctly used. The goal here is *not* to find the last node, but to do something with each node. Also, this code will raise an exception when the list is empty (i.e. when `self.head` is `None`). It uses an `if` inside the loop to cover for the fact that this type of loop stops one step earlier, and so works around that "problem" and still covers for the missing step.

In short, this was the wrong type of loop! It should have been coded like this:

```
current = self.head
while current:
    print(current.value)
    current = current.next
```

### Case 3

```
while current and counter < position:
    if counter == position - 1:
        new_element.next = current.next
        current.next = new_element
    current = current.next
    counter += 1
```

Here we want to iterate until we found the node that precedes the given position, and then the new node is inserted after it. There is no interest here to find the *last* node and do something with it after the loop, so this is the correct type of loop (the first type).